# Convergence of sequence as $O(1/n)$ using damped iterations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to understand the argument for convergence [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~eryu/papers/monotone_notes.pdf) (page 16) for damped iterations of non-expansive maps.

Say we have a sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ that is generated as $x^n = \theta F(x^{n-1})+(1-\theta)x^{n-1}$ for a given map $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which is non-expansive, i.e.$\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$.

It follows (using an identity) that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\|F(x^j) - x^j\|_2^2 \leq \frac{\|x^0-x^\star\|_2^2}{\theta(1-\theta)}$$
and so clearly $\|F(x^n) - x^n\|_{2}^{2} \rightarrow 0$. However, I fail to see how this implies
$$ \min_{j=0,1,...,k}\|F(x^j)-x^j\|_2^2 \leq \frac{\|x^0 - x^\star\|_2^2}{(k+1)\theta(1-\theta)}$$
and even if it did, how does this imply convergence of $\{x^k\}$ to a fixed-point?

Comment: For the inequality: The minimum is less than or equal to the mean. And the mean is obviously less than or equal to the RHS

Comment: @AlexR - Yes, I see that clearly now, thank you. So we've bounded the smallest term, but it seems that isn't enough to get convergence to me.

Comment: Convergence to zero implies that eventually the minimum is the last index for a subsequence. That should get you there by uniqueness of the limit.

Comment: Your argument makes intuitive sense to me now.  But, if I take the limit as $k$ goes to $\infty$ then $\|F(x^k)-x^k\|$ must go to zero hence $F(x^k)$ and $x^k$ must get closer and closer together, but how does this imply that they converge to the same value? Couldn't they both be moving in a way that they get closer to one another perpetually?

Comment: We have a cauchy sequence in a compact domain, so it converges. The compact domain is given by $\overline{B_{\frac1{\sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}} \|x^0 - x^\ast\|_2}(x^0)}$ due to the first equation.

Comment: @AlexR - I see. It looks like the $\displaystyle \min_{j=0,1,...,k}\|F(x^j)-x^j\|_2^2 \leq \frac{\|x^0 - x^\star\|_2^2}{(k+1)\theta(1-\theta)}$ isn't necessary for convergence then, am I correct? It's just a comment on the rate I believe.

Comment: Yes, I think so. It implies $\mathcal O(n^{-1})$ convergence.

Comment: So, to ensure I understood: from the summation
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\|F(x^j) - x^j\|_2^2 \leq \frac{\|x^0-x^\star\|_2^2}{\theta(1-\theta)} \hspace{2em}(1)
$$
we conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \|F(x^k)-x^k\|_2^2 = 0$ hence $\{x^k\}$ is Cauchy (is there a name for this implication?) on a compact domain and therefore goes to some unique limit point. The fact the limit point is a fixed-point of $F$ is due to the term $\|F(x^k)-x^k\|$ needing to be zero eventually.

Comment: Actually we need the compactness to conclude that the sequence is Cauchy. The rest is fine.